# get width height of iframe content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

hi i want if any one use my url on iframe my code detected the ifame and also its size
like

```
<iframe name="test" src="http://mydomin.com/show.php" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

if any one use like `mydomin` on iframe my `show.php` file detect it use our url on iframe and his sizes also.
can its possible? please tell me how to do it

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, you want to resize your iframe on other's site right? if that is so you can't do so...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think you might be referring to the practice of frame busting? In that case, read this: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-framebuster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your iframe you need to add the script:

```
if (window !== top) {
  alert(window.innerWidth + ',' + window.innerHeight);
}
```

This script check if your page run in iframe: `(window !== top)`

Then `alert` the width and height.

**Demo:**

http://output.jsbin.com/gabeze

**Update**

For prevent website to embed yours, the best way I know is in the server.

Just return the header `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY`.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a ,  or  . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: i try this for prevent all frame<br/>    <script  type="text/javascript">if (top != self) { 
   top.location = self.location; 
} </script>     <br/>but its not work when anyone use    sandbox attribute on iframe    <br/> please tell me for this what i do?

Comment: I was updated my answer, please check if this answer your comment.